# gulp-angular2 task is not working

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp

I am working on a gulpfile where i writin this task:

```
    var tsProject = ts.createProject('app/Resources/public/angular/tsconfig.json');
    gulp.task('angular-2', function () {
      var tsResult = tsProject.src() // instead of gulp.src(...)
            .pipe(ts(tsProject));

      return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
});
```

I am completely new to this how do I test this or can somebody help me write this task?

If I run gulp-watch or default it returns me this errors but it is building but with erros:

[image]

Comment: so you want the build to fail on error? can you try this option inside you tsconfig `noEmitOnError: true`

Comment: I did that where is that good for?

Comment: It supposed not to produce any output when there is an error, I think

Comment: @koox00 okay, maybe have some ideas where the errors come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gulp task seems ok to me, the errors are in your code.

e.g:
[image]

you have from left to right:

*file(line,column): description*

So the first one says that your `booking-search.component.ts` in line 1 is requiring a method from a module and that method does not exit , maybe you mistyped.

Look in your files and try to correct all the errors, If you cannot solve a specific one post a new question about what you have tried and ask for help.